# Change Tracking Table of a table Not tracking Updation of a Row With "U" SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION on Same Row which is inserted first

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, change-tracking

The Problem I am Getting is that I have Enabled Tracking of Every table in Database Whenever a row is Inserted  it tracks that row and event When an Updatie Operation is performed on any row it is tracked
 but

> When A Row is Inserted in table it is Tracked But When the same row is
>   Updated it does Not Track it with **"U" Value in Column SYS_Change_Operation** while its shows the Updated Values But With **"I" Value in Column SYS_Change_Operation**

Comment: Yes, that's how [change tracking works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb933875.aspx): "If an application requires information about all the changes that were made and the intermediate values of the changed data, using change data capture, instead of change tracking, might be appropriate. ". It explicitly doesn't offer you *all* intermediate states.

Comment: Also, just as a side/style note. Capital letters should be used at the start of sentences and for proper nouns. Not for the start of random words within sentences.